# android background in xml: tranparency become black not white

Tags: android, xml, background, alpha-transparency

I make a xml file for android interface. In this xml, there's an expendable items. I want to add background for this xml with tansparency (alpha) but when i add bacground in relative layout with alpha like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:alpha="0.2"
tools:context=".ListGestureActivity" >
```

that will make background transparency become black not white. In other xml happened like that too.
But in other xml i tried to do this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context=".HintGestureActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:alpha="0.3"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    />
```

it worked. But in xml with expendable items didn't work.
Do you any suggestion?

Comment: what is the value of @drawable/background?

Comment: In `AndroidMenifest.xml`, which theme you are using for `activity`? `Dark` or `Light`? If `Dark`, make it `Light` and try it. tell the results.

Comment: @drawable/bacground is the image that i want to make it for the background

Comment: to MrSuS -- I don't use any theme

Answer (score 0):

U can do something like this

```
android:background="#00564678"
```

For Ex:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:alpha="0.3"
    android:background="#00564678"
    />
```

Comment: i want make @drawable/background as my interface background

Comment: color-- "#00564678" is transparent color. Just set background using this only.

Answer (score 0):

By default it takes black color as your background color and after that, if you apply transparency then you will not get desired output.Therefore, first you need to set some background color after that apply `alpha` on that. Try this :

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:alpha="0.2"
tools:context=".ListGestureActivity" >
```

Comment: i want make @drawable/background as my interface background

Comment: What do you mean by "making `@drawable/backgroud` as your interface"? I am not getting what you are trying to do?